# Get Role with Description for selected User

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am new to MVC.  I have a Details View with a ViewModel for showing data for a selected User.  I want to list the Roles that the User has and I also want a Description of the Role, and the Id of the Role.

I am able to get the Roles for the selected ApplicationUser with this:

```
model.UserRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(model.AppUser);
```

I don't know how to get the Description for each of the roles and display it in my Details View.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  I hope this helps somebody.  I don't know if this is the best or most efficient way, but it is working.  I got the user roles with the following:

```js
//Get the User Roles
IList<String> userRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(model.AppUser);
```

I use this for getting the role descriptions:

```js
List<String> roleDescription = new List<String>();

if (userRoles.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (string r in userRoles)
    {
        //Get the Description for the assigned Role
        var desc = _roleManager.Roles.Where(n => n.Name == r).Select(d => d.Description).Single();
        roleDescription.Add(desc.ToString());
    }

    //Using Tuple to combine text in [Role] | [Description] format in View
    var roleWithDesc = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < userRoles.Count; i++)
    {    
         roleWithDesc.Add(Tuple.Create(userRoles[i].ToString(), roleDescription[i].ToString()));
    }

    model.UserRoles = roleWithDesc;
}
```

Here is the code in my ViewModel:

```js
public ApplicationUser AppUser { get; set; }

public Employee Employee { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "User Roles")]
public List<Tuple<string, string>> UserRoles { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Available Roles")]
public List<Tuple<string, string>> AllRoles { get; set; }
```